# Making Empty C++ Project: General exception (Exception from HRESULT:0x80131500) Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make a new C++ empty project in Visual Studio Community 2015. However, as soon as I just hit okay, it tells me One or more errors have occured, and general exception (Exception from HRESULT:0x80131500).

I've been trying to look online for other results, but none have really helped so far and I was wondering if anyone here knew how to fix it.

I've tried re installing it and even tried Windows Ultimate 2013 and I'd still be unable to make an empty project.

Comment: Are you running a virus scanner?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No? I'm on Windows 10 if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it stopped working when I've tried to switch my solution from "Debug" to "Release" configuration. After that VS started to fail to load my projects or create new ones with the message you have mentioned (Exception from HRESULT:0x80131500).

What I did was trying to create new C# project on which I have got much more clear and useful message, saying that VS 2015 can not open the following file:

```
C\ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
```

When I have checked this file I have found it to be corrupted in a weird way - size of the file was the same as the original but about 80% of the file was just a garbage. After that I have downloaded the original file from [Microsoft reference source website](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#MSBuildFiles/C/ProgramFiles(x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin_/amd64/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets) and it fixed it.